# Return value from 'Future' function

Tags: flutter, dart, return, future

I hope you can help me with getting a return value out of a future function.
I created a local MariaDB and connect to it with the `mysql1` package. The next step is to get a value whenever a table is empty or not (indicates as 0 or 1). I archive that behavior with the following SQL query `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table);`

---

Function to create a db connection.

```
//creates connection to local database. (used in .this((conn){}) function)
  Future<MySqlConnection> getConnection() async {
    var settings = ConnectionSettings(
      host: host!,
      port: port!,
      user: user,
      password: password,
      db: db,
    );
    return await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
  }
```

---

My Function that should return 0 or 1, let me explan the code block down below.

1. `getConnection()` create database connection
2. trigger `.then()` to work with the output as `conn`
3. execute SQL query
4. format SQL query to just 0 or 1
5. **Missing:** should return the value when checkIfTableIsEmpty() is called

---

```
  //should return 0 or 1 depending if table is empty or not.
  checkIfTableIsEmpty(String table) async {
    //holds the sql query that should get executed.
    String sql = 'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM $table);';

    //this should get returned after annitialised.
    String? globalNumber;

    //!!! creates the value 0 or 1 !!!
 await getConnection().then(                      // (1)
      (conn) async {                        // (2) 
        //output: result = (Fields: {EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master_key): 1})
        Results result = await conn.query(sql); //(3)
        String? number;

        for (var row in result) {.          // (4) <---- format output to just 0 or 1
          number = '${row[0]}';
        }

        globalNumber = number;             
        print('$globalNumber'); // <---- output is 1
        return globalNumber;
      });

    // (5) globalNumber should get printed
    print('$globalNumber'); // <---- output null, this should be 1
  }
```

---

Function that is currently returning `null` but should get value of globalNumber var.

```
 //call the function and print result.
 void testFunction() async {
    print(checkIfTableIsEmpty('master_key'));
  }
```

Comment: you don't return anything in `checkIfTableIsEmpty` method. Instead of doing `getConnection().then` do `await getConnection()` to avoid having callbacks

Comment: Hello @Almis i changed your suggestion to the code.

Comment: no I don't mean `await getConnection().then`. What you need to do is `var conn = await getConnection();` and then continue as it is

Answer (score 0):

Hello i found the solution for my problem. I had to await on the result and delete the .then() function to avoid having callbacks. (See the comment of @Almis).

Thanks @Almis for the code improvement.
This is my final function that return 0 or 1.

```
checkIfTableIsEmpty(String table) async {
    String sql = 'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM $table);';
    String? globalNumber;

    var conn = await getConnection();

    Results result = await conn.query(sql);

    for (var row in result) {
      globalNumber = '${row[0]}';
    }

    return globalNumber;
  }

  void testFunction() async {
    var x = await checkIfTableIsEmpty('master_key');
    print(x);
  }
```